# use variable value as object with jquery/javascript

Tags: jquery, variables, object, raphael

i have something like that :

```
var StateName =  [obj.data('name')];
StateName.click(function(e){ etc....
```

So, it gives me the right name (Texas), but it says in the console :

```
Object usa.Texas has no method 'click'
```

If i write it directly like:

```
usa.Texas.click(function(e){ etc....
```

it works...

thank you

Comment: [obj.data('name')] is a javascript array with one element you need a jqueryobject to use thc click method. So to help you we need to now whats the relation between obj.data('name') and usa.Texas (the last one appears to be a jquery object.

Comment: it looks like you have an existing `usa` object?  So perhaps `state = usa[obj.data('name')]`

Comment: obj.data('name') is a value in Raphaeljs, so it gives directly the string : usa.Texas, so I tried StateName[0] but as it is a string, it gives me : u  -- for the first letter of usa.Texas...I'm still trying to get it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out in the comments, obj.data('name') returns a string. You can't access a JavaScript Object like that, but you can access properties of it by passing a string.

You could do something like that:

```
// Get Name, split to extract the property portion
var StateName = obj.data('name').split('.')[1];

// Bind to specific state
usa[StateName].click(......
```

If you the need name of the object (usa), you could nest all of your (assuming) country objects in another object.

```
// Wrap in object
var countries = {usa: { texas: jQuery() }}

// Get Name, split to extract portions
var CountryState = obj.data('name').split('.');
var Country = CountryState[0];
var State = CountryState[1];

// Bind to country / state
countries[Country][State].click(.......
```